# Vuex state boolen property shows undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuex, state-management

I have a boolean state property but it's showing me undefined?

```
export default {
    state: {
        userStateChanged: false,
...
```

While fetching the data I have done a `console.log` on this state property and the console is showing undefined

```
        async FETCH_ALL_USERS(context, page) {

            console.log('state changed?', this.state.userStateChanged);

            if (this.state.userStateChanged === false) {
                return this.state.users;
            } else {
                console.log('return new set');
                const user  = await axios.get("/api/user?page=" + page);
                context.commit('SET_ALL_USERS', user.data);
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should access store state through `context`.

```
async FETCH_ALL_USERS(context, page) {

            console.log('state changed?', context.state.userStateChanged);

            if (context.state.userStateChanged === false) {
                return context.state.users;
            } else {
                console.log('return new set');
                const user  = await axios.get("/api/user?page=" + page);
                context.commit('SET_ALL_USERS', user.data);
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to access the store before accessing the state.
so instead of `console.log('state changed?', this.state.userStateChanged);`  do `console.log('state changed?', this.$store.state.userStateChanged);`

Comment: No the page does not load, and strangely enough, I don't get any errors on the console as well.